# creating a call back for AsyncTask in a model to update an activity

Tags: android, model-view-controller, model, android-asynctask

I'm creating an app in an MVC pattern... and I'm trying to do most of the data getting and manipulation on the Model side of things so I don't clutter up the Activities with code that does not belong there, but the one thing that's tripping me up a bit is AsyncTask... from what I've seen it seems that this is called most of the time in the UI because it allows you to update. the problem with that is I am doing all my network calls using AsyncTask from my model not my activity. But I still want to update my UI when cretin things happen such as a network  call returned something put it in the ui.. so is there a way to make a call back from a model to the Activity or something to that effect, so I don't have to put that code in the activity? 
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an interface which acts as an update "listener" in your Model. That way, your activity can register with the listener when it is active and receive notifications of changes accordingly.

There are many examples (and built-in listener classes) - here is one:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_interfaces.htm

Creating an interface in your Activity that is registered in your model allows your model to notify the interface of changed data in order to update properly. If you implement your model as a service or maintain instances of them in a service, then you can bind to the service and then register your listener assuming your model processing extends beyond the life of activities.

If not, AsyncTask is where model processing should occur and you can implement your model synchronously and use listeners to monitor it.